# Burn Win10 install media on Win7, without upgrading Win7?

Tags: windows, installation, iso-image, dvd-burning, .net-3.5

I'm trying to create Win10 installation media for a PC that shipped with Win10, but without a Win10 dvd.  This PC must stay offline.

At a Win7 PC that was online, I tried to get an ISO image by running Microsoft's MediaCreationTool.exe [Using the tool to create installation media (USB flash drive, DVD, or ISO file) to install Windows 10 on a different PC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/Windows10).  But it looked like that tool was trying to upgrade that Win7 PC to Win10 (recall all those sneaky Windows Updates over the past few years).  So I panicked and killed the tool.

When I search for how to burn a Win10 install dvd on the Win10 PC, or for where to get a Win10 iso, I end up at that same web page.

How can I build the iso from the offline Win10 PC?  (If I run MediaCreationTool.exe there, it complains that the PC is offline.)

Or can I trust MediaCreationTool.exe to not mangle the Win7 PC?

(All I'm actually trying to do is [install .NET 3.5](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20170203-OfflineInstallationOfNet35InWindows10.html) on the offline Win10 PC, so it can run a [miniDSP](https://www.minidsp.com/products/minidsp-in-a-box/minidsp-2x4-hd) USB audio interface.)

Comment: I have not used this tool yet so I won't post as an answer however reading the link you provided, this tool does many things including both upgrading the machine you run it on OR creating install media.  My reading suggests it's safe if you choose the options to just create media.
You can/should take an image/backup of the Win 7 machine for extra security anyway (it's just good practice) so if the installer borks the install you can just roll back.

Comment: Was that OR or XOR? :)

Comment: Lol.  I *believe* it's an XOR but that's why I suggested the backups.  Should have em running every day anyway... ;)

Comment: Now the silly thing is, it will show you an iso *if* you're on a non windows user agent. Would using a livecd or switching your user agent be a option?

Comment: Yes, but https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/ is deprecated.  I can ssh to a linux box, but when I run its command-line browser **links**, I can't figure out how to get to the iso.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune I expect that the exe is basically a stub and once you tell it you want to create an iso it will DL it for you.  I see you got the ISO from PatrikN so that's good enough but I would have liked to know if it the tool behaves as expected.  Not exactly sure but I suspect you should write up the final solution as an answer here and accept it as a self-answered question so this closes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Selecting **Create installation media for another PC** on the **What do you want to do?** page, should allow you to download and burn an ISO from the Windows 7  PC, so maybe you selected the wrong alternative. But before you get so far, it "Makes some things ready" (twice) and you have to accept the license terms in between, so keep calm while pressing **Next** some (3) times :-)

[The exact instructions you shall follow on the download page.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10#d2784474-fdb0-4e9d-9e47-5e88c0e053ec)

Alternatively, if you have access to a PC with an OS other than Windows 7, 8 and 10 (like Linux or macOS), you can download ISOs from this link instead: [Download Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)

Comment: Welcome to SU Patrik.  That link is to the same page that OP linked does not answer his question.  Please read questions more thoroughly in the future and make sure your answers are relevant/helpful.  I'd suggest you rewrite or pull this answer as it merits downvotes and I don't want that to happen to a new user.

Comment: I'm sorry I was to quick and didn't verify my answer. It apparently depends on from what OS you are visiting the link. I did it from macOS, where I got to a page, where I could directly download the ISO files. _"You’ve been routed to this page because the operating system you’re using won’t support the Windows 10 media creation tool and we want to make sure you can download Windows 10. ... You can use this page to download a disc image (ISO file) ..."_ On Win7, 8 and 10 you are redirected to the page OP linked to. I'll update my answer.

Comment: "Keep calm" would be fine, if only the win7 instance were a VM that I could wipe and spin up again in twenty seconds.

Comment: After PatrickN's update, his link still asks to first run MediaCreationTool.exe. Back to where I started.

Comment: Well, the "keep calm" was just a way of answering **Yes** to your question _Or can I trust MediaCreationTool.exe to not mangle the win7 PC?_

Comment: Here are two links to Windows 10 English International valid for 24 hours: [32-bit](https://software-download.microsoft.com/db/Win10_1709_EnglishInternational_x32.iso?t=f2f5e7c0-000c-40a2-8904-be00cc9b2edb&e=1519097914&h=99d2d0040476ed7b1ea85bf26261837b) [64-bit](https://software-download.microsoft.com/db/Win10_1709_EnglishInternational_x64.iso?t=f2f5e7c0-000c-40a2-8904-be00cc9b2edb&e=1519097914&h=fe3f278b1d5c17c780a082b19a3b6a43). I got those by going to the link from a non-Win OS, so if you need another language, you can fire up a live-CD/DVD or use some other method or just ask for them :-)

Comment: Downloaded the 64-bit ISO.  Tomorrow I'll move it via thumbdrive to the win10 PC, once I find a thumbdrive formatted with a file system that accepts 4.7 GB files.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! I'll hope it will work. If you need additional help, feel free to ask. If you feel my effort to help you was helpful, I would appreciate accepting my answer.